# Permanently delete Favorites and Searches folders

Tags: windows-7

How do I go about deleting these two folders that seems to regenerate every time I delete them?

I've never used these folders, and I don't want folders there that I don't use. How do I get rid of them and stop them from coming back?

Comment: Can you explain where exactly these folders are?  Such as " C:\Example\Favorites ".  Or provide a screenshot of what you are looking at?  Also if you have tried methods of getting rid of them please articulate that as well for us.

Comment: They appear in my user folder "C:\users\username" and if I delete them, they'll reappear at a later time.

Answer (score -1):

The folders you are talking about are linked to Internet Explorer, which is an integrated part of the Windows operating system, which means that you cannot remove it.  I am venturing a guess that since they are associated with IE that you are also limited in how you can alter them as well.  Fortunately since you are likely not using IE they will have a completely negligible footprint on your Hard drive (mine are 88kb and 12kb respectively).

This is a workaround to your issue, but I would recommend simply hiding them, so you don't have to see them anymore.  To do this right click on the folder, select properties, check the "Hidden" box, and select "OK".  They will both at least not be viewable to you anymore, and less of a nuisance.

Comment: You would think you'd be able to get rid of this regeneration in the registry or something...

Comment: Well you are talking about a fairly radical change in functionality to a part of the operating system itself.  It's going to be a much more involved process than simply going in and deleting or changing a key or two.  That is why I recommend the above, because it is definitely possible, much easier, and achieves nearly the same result.

Comment: Yes, but if I was to ever display my user folder on the left pane in windows explorer (where favorites, computer, etc. are), it would show them.